# MASM Syntax Highlighting in C++ for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So, I had Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and everything was great.

However, I was confused, thought I wanted MASM, and installed the SDK.  This causes strange problems for syntax highlighting.  When I'm editing a C/C++ file, for instance, a lot of words (e.g., "data", "add", "sub", "mul", "div", "eax", etc.) are highlighted.

At first, I thought I'd just learn to live with it, but it has gotten annoying.

I could find nothing online, so, I deleted the MASM folder completely (method of uninstallation), uninstalled Visual Studio, and then installed it again.

I fired it up, and the problem persists.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check usertype.dat file(open it in VS or notepad) in the Visual Studio folder. I think highlighted words is there.

Comment: Found it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE.  I see a lot of entries there, including some that overlap with C/C++ (e.g., "if").  Deleting the entire file's contents solves the problem.  Thanks!